# Need help running an animation based on data from a URLSession (Swift3)

Tags: ios, animation, asynchronous, swift3

I am at my wits end here. I have tried everything I can think of, and CANNOT get this to work.

I feel like what I am trying to do here SHOULD be simple - but Swift is making it ridiculously difficult, and I am getting frustrated.

Ultimately, all I want to do is get a single piece of data from a web script (it will return a float), and then use that float to animate a UIView.

So - just for simplicities sake - we'll assume the web script returns "50.0". I then want to take that number, and animate a UIView to go from 0px to 50px tall.

I have read that you cannot get data from an asynchronous task, and that you basically have to run any tasks that you want run with that data inside of the closure. However... when I try to run my animations inside the closure, Xcode slaps my wrists and tells me that I am trying to modify AutoLayout properties in a different thread. So what the heck am I supposed to do?

Below is my code, commented as best as I can:

To start, I have a UIView in my ViewController that has a purple background. I am adding a sub-view into this UIView that is green, and will grow vertically based on the returned value of the web script, effectively making a "meter" (see image).

[image]

```
//This variable is passed in from the Segue & will eventually be passed to the web script, so it knows which ID to pull the data from.
var deviceID: String = ""


//This is a programmatically created UIView that will be added as a subview to the UIView that has been dragged to the View Controller. Based on the image, this will eventually be the "green" rectangle that you see.
let oilReading = UIView()


//This is the outlet for the UIView that I dragged into the ViewController. Based on the image, this is the purple background.
@IBOutlet weak var tankRep: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    //This block styles the purple block to give it rounded corners & a shadow.
    tankRep.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    tankRep.clipsToBounds = true
    tankRep.layer.masksToBounds = false;
    tankRep.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0);
    tankRep.layer.shadowRadius = 8;
    tankRep.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;



    //These lines set some default styles for the green block (color & position)
    oilReading.frame = CGRect(x: tankRep.bounds.origin.x, y: CGFloat(tankRep.bounds.height), width: CGFloat(100), height: CGFloat(0))
    oilReading.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 56/255, green: 221/255, blue: 166/255, alpha: 1.0)


    //These lines create a mask for the green block so the corners are rounded.
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: Int(oilMeterHeight)), byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    self.oilReading.layer.mask = maskLayer

    //Add the green block as a subview to the purple block
    tankRep.addSubview(oilReading)
    tankRep.sendSubview(toBack: oilReading)

    //================================================================
    // THIS NEEDS TO RUN BASED ON THE VALUE OF THE WEB SCRIPT
    // Where I am referencing "oilMeterHeight" is what would ultimately come from the web script
    //================================================================

    UIView.transition(with: oilReading, duration: 1.0, animations: {self.oilReading.frame = CGRect(x: self.tankRep.bounds.origin.x, y: CGFloat(self.tankRep.bounds.height - CGFloat(oilMeterHeight)), width: 100, height: CGFloat(oilMeterHeight))}, completion: nil)



    //This calls the function that runs the webscript
    getMeterHeight(deviceID: deviceID)
}


private func getMeterHeight(deviceID: String) {

    guard let URL = URL(string: "http://www.mywebsite.com/getLatestReading.php") else {return}
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let bodyObject: [String: String] = [
        "deviceID": deviceID
    ]

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyObject, options: [])
    var responseString: NSString = ""

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if (error == nil) {
            responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!

            //This is the value that I need to get out of this unescapable black hole
            let oilMeterHeight = 175 * responseString.doubleValue;

            //Alternately, if I cannot get the previously set value out of this method, then I would like to run the following code - which in its current state does not work...
            //UIView.transition(with: self.oilReading, duration: 1.0, animations: {self.oilReading.frame = CGRect(x: self.tankRep.bounds.origin.x, y: CGFloat(self.tankRep.bounds.height - CGFloat(oilMeterHeight)), width: 100, height: CGFloat(oilMeterHeight))}, completion: nil)
        } else {
            // Failure
            print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS you can not update the UI on the background thread. To update the UI , write your code in main thread like this:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
      //update your UI here 
    }
```

In your case, to animate the view with the value get in response of web service, write this block just after the getting the result.If everything is right with your api call, then your getMeterHeight method should look like this:

```
private func getMeterHeight(deviceID: String) {

    guard let URL = URL(string: "http://www.mywebsite.com/getLatestReading.php") else {return}
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let bodyObject: [String: String] = [
    "deviceID": deviceID
    ]

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyObject, options: [])
    var responseString: NSString = ""

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    data, response, error in

     if (error == nil) {
        responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!

        //This is the value that I need to get out of this unescapable black hole
        let oilMeterHeight = 175 * responseString.doubleValue;

         DispatchQueue.main.async{
          //update your UI here 
           UIView.transition(with: self.oilReading, duration: 1.0, animations: {self.oilReading.frame = CGRect(x: self.tankRep.bounds.origin.x, y: CGFloat(self.tankRep.bounds.height - CGFloat(oilMeterHeight)), width: 100, height: CGFloat(oilMeterHeight))}, completion: nil)

        }
     } else {
        // Failure
        print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
    }
}

task.resume()
    }
```